# call onActivityResult() repeatedly

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

So me and my group are having a project in school. We decided to make an app. The app is gonna work like this:
The user can press on the screen and the app will ask what the user want's to do.
The user then can says some different things, like (Battery, vibration, and more). If the user says battery it will tell the battery status on the phone. If the user says vibration the app is gonna ask how much and the user is gonna say a number between 0 - 100 (this number is going to be sent to the project we building). If the user says an address it will take it and open up google maps and start how to walk there.

So the app is working fine but one thing. When a user says an address we want the app to ask the user if the address is correct. So the problem we have is to be able to check that.

Have in mind that no one of us have done a app before xD.

So what you can see in the code under this is that we just want it to be able to ask the user one more time in the vibration and default section.

```
/**
 * What to do when button is clicked.
 * @param view is the information on the button.
 */
public void onClick(View view) throws InterruptedException {
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        playMusic(R.raw.where_to_go);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        Intent speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, 
                              RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Tala!");
        startActivityForResult(speechIntent, 1);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            string = matches.get(0).toString();
            switch (string) {
                case "battery":
                    int speech = textToSpeech.speak("Phone" + battery.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    break;
                case "vibration":
                    //Ask for a number between 0 - 100
                    //insert code for vibration control here
                    break;
                default:
                    string1 = string;
                    speech = textToSpeech.speak("Going to " + string1, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                    //Check if the address is correct

                    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + string + "&mode=w"));
                    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                    startActivity(intent);


                    break;

            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: is there any code for the section //Check if the address is correct?

Comment: no that's what we need help with. So what that comment means is that we want the code to ask the user to say "yes" or "no".

Comment: Can you log the value of resultCode and data intent each time onActivityResult() is called ?

Comment: sure I can, I was thinking if it is possible to make it recursive? But the thing is it starts a new activity so what I understand is that you can see it as 2 Threads.